# MobX - Filter asMap from computed value?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I am trying `asMap` and want to output the book titles that match the `coverType`:

Here is the `BookStore`:

```
class BookStore {
    @observable coverType = 'soft';
    @observable booksByIdMap = asMap({
      "88cd7621": {
        "id": "88cd7621",
        "title": "The Secret",
        "coverType": 'soft'
      },
      "88cd7622": {
        "id": "88cd7622",
        "title": "The Alchemist",
        "coverType": 'hard'
      },
      "88cd7623": {
        "id": "88cd7623",
        "title": "Javascript",
        "coverType": 'soft'
      }
    });

    @computed get byCoverType() {
      return this.booksByIdMap.filter(book => book.coverType == this.coverType);
    }
}
```

Here is the UI:

```
const bookStore = new BookStore();

const BookViewItem = observer(({book}) => 
    <li>
        {book.title}
    </li>
);

@observer
class BookView extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Books With Cover Type: {bookStore.coverType}</h1>
      <ul>
        {bookStore.byCoverType().map(book => 
          <BookViewItem book={book} key={book.id} />
         )}
      </ul>
     </div>
  }
}
```

But it does not render the book titles based on the current `coverType` value.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ob7v1gk5/

How can I output the book titles using the computed `Bookstore.byCoverType` filtered results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MobX map is not an array, so it does not have filter and other array specific methods. Check the [**documentation to see what methods you can use**](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/map.html).

You could e.g. use the `values` method and then use `filter` on the resulting array [**like this**](http://jsbin.com/wiwatumuvo/1/edit?js,output):

```
class BookStore {
  @observable coverType = 'soft';
  @observable booksByIdMap = asMap({
    "88cd7621": {
      "id": "88cd7621",
      "title": "The Secret",
      "coverType": 'soft'
    },
    "88cd7622": {
      "id": "88cd7622",
      "title": "The Alchemist",
      "coverType": 'hard'
    },
    "88cd7623": {
      "id": "88cd7623",
      "title": "Javascript",
      "coverType": 'soft'
    },
  });

  @computed get byCoverType() {
    return this.booksByIdMap.values().filter(b => b.coverType === this.coverType);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tholle, this works quiet well, but I am having a hard time filtering via `bookIdsArray`. Here is the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/pasufinufe/1/edit?js,output, with the `bookIdsArray ` passed but nothing shows up. I am not sure how to filter the original map by an array of the book ids, so I return them from the map in the computed `byBookId`

Comment: @Wonka You're welcome. That wasn't even part of your question. Try `this.booksByIdMap.values().filter(b => bookIdsArray.includes(b.id));`

Comment: Yup you're right, sorry but I just wanted to make sure I understood how to filter the map by ids as well as computed. Thank you @Tholle for clearing that up :)